# Why does df['text'].str.contains('.') always return True?

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing some python code to replace punctuation in a column of strings in a pandas DataFrame. After replacement, I notice that testing existence of '.' within the resulting string always returns True.

I am using Python 3.7 and spotted this detail while using PyCharm. I have however, been able to reproduce the result in Jupyter Notebooks.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['My string.'], columns=['Text'])
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('[^\w\s]', '')
print(df['Text'].str.contains('.'))

>>> 0  True
```

I would expect to False as the character '.' was replaced with the empty string. The string itself looks to have had its punctuation removed, but interestingly, the test of existence still returns True. Repeating this for other punctuation characters returns the expected value, False. Can anyone explain if this is expected behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: string.replace will find the exact string `[^\w\s]` and replace it, which is not present in the dataframe, also `'[^\w\s]'` looks like regex, are you trying `re.sub` ?

Comment: `.` is a regex class meaning 'literally any character', use `'\.'` - the regex escape character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(df['Text'].str.contains('.',regex=False))
>>> 0  False
```

`'.'`is any character except line break in regex expresion , you need to tell to pandas if you want to use regex or not

Comment: good answer, you might want to add a brief explanation and perhaps point towards the `in` operator

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chris A and sygneto for pointing this out - after checking pandas documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html, it can be confirmed that the first argument to contains() is a regex pattern. Setting regex to False treats the pattern as a raw string, rather than the wildcard, resolving the issue.

Comment: if my answer was good enough please accept it